# 'Subcircuit is undefined' when designing PWM with TL493 in PSPICE

Tags: pwm, duty-cycle

I am trying to design a PWM for my converter using TL493 in Pspice and i am getting an error.

ERROR(ORPSIM-15108): Subcircuit model591_tl493 used by X_U1 is undefined

i am a beginner to both Pspice and circuit, so i don't know what it means. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably forgot to add the corresponding library model to your simulation. Go to

```
Simulation Profiles -> Configuration Files -> Library -> Browse
```

and add the file which should be named something like `TL493_pspice_model.txt` to your simulation.

Comment: I tried this but there is no "TL493_pspice_model.txt" in the library, so what to do next.